# C# using ++ operator in different class

Tags: c#, operators

I am trying to create a class for something and I need to use the ++ and -- operator like in an int. I have an error to where it says "Overloadable binary operator expected" but I don't know what that means. Here is my code:

```
        public static int operator ++(TriggerMeter m, int value)
    {
        if (m != null)
        {
            int newValue = m.Triggeredness + value;
            m.Triggeredness = newValue;
            return newValue;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The operator `++` is an unary operator, and you have tried to treat it like a binary operator. also the returning type should be the containing type.

So your code correct signature should be:

```
public static TriggerMeter operator ++(TriggerMeter m)
```

However, it seems that you wanted to override the `+` operator, which would be the same as you've implemented, just replacing the `++` with `+`.

**Be careful** as you are changing the value in the object as well as returning it which might not be an obvious (and natural) usage and might lead to bugs.